# ActiveMQ - Using JMX how can I get a job's payload from its jobid?

Tags: activemq-classic

So, I can find a list of scheduled jobs using the 'AllJobs' attribute of the jobScheduler MBean - but i'd like to then find details of each jobs payload.

Also, if there is a better way that would be interesting to know.

Using ActiveMQ v5.4.2

Comment: If you can't find a JMX operation etc then this is not possible. But it sounds like a nice enhancement, and you can log a JIRA ticket about this at Apache ActiveMQ - http://activemq.apache.org/support.html

Comment: Thanks, will try raising a ticket and see what they say.  I'll put up a link when I've got round to it!